# How to recover deleted system files in MSMQ

Tags: msmq, msmq-wcf, msmqintegrationbinding, msmqbinding, msmq-transaction

I Unfortunatly deleted the System Files of MSMQ under,

```
C:\Windows\System32\msmq\storage\lqs
```

now i unable to send and receive messages from Queue.

How to recover the deleted files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the files are not in the wastebasket and you don't have a backup then you will need to recreate them.

System queues can be recreated by copying the corresponding files from another machine. The file names for system files are ones with a low number. Otherwise, try using the "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSMQ\Parameters\LogDataCreated" registry value.

Non-system queues will need to be recreated through Computer Management.

Comment: Yesh, works by copying files from another mechine and restart the mechine.... thanks